# How to conditionally transform with checks for surrounding tag in xml/xsl?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML structure:

```
...
<tag1>content1</tag1>
<tag2/>
<tag3>content<b>3</b></tag3>
<tag4><ul>....</ul></tag4>
...
```

If there is no surrounding tag from a list (case 1+3), it should translate to `<p>(tag-content)</p>`, if it is empty (case2), it should translate to nothing and if it has *certain* surrounding tags form a list (like ul, div) (case4), it should just transform to the tag-content without surrounding p.

What would be the test-expression for that cases in the `<xsl:when>`s?

This should work in the browser, so im limited to XSL 1.0.

Comment: There are no "tags" is XSLT. The 4 **elements** that you show contain either text nodes only (1), no nodes at all (2), a mixture of text nodes and elements (3) or elements only (4). Rethink your question in those terms.

Comment: SaxonJS 2 from Saxonica allows you to run XSLT 3.0 in the browser.